# sort and sum for large data files

Tags: sorting, awk, uniq

I have to process a file that `sort` does not seem to be able to handle.
The files are apprx. 3 GB each.

The input is as follows:

```
last-j  nmod+j+n    year-n 9492
last-j  nmod+j+n    night-n 8075
first-j nmod+j+n-the    time-n 7749
same-j  nmod+j+n-the    time-n 7530
other-j nmod+j+n-the    hand-n 5319
ast-j   nmod+j+n   year-n 1000
last-j   nmod+j+n   night-n 5000
first-j   nmod+j+n-the   time-n 1000
same-j   nmod+j+n-the   time-n 3000
other-j   nmod+j+n-the   hand-n 200
```

In which I need to sum the numbers of corresponding duplicates.

so the desired output would be as follows:

```
   last-j   nmod+j+n    year-n 10492
    last-j  nmod+j+n    night-n 13075
    first-j nmod+j+n-the    time-n 8749
    same-j  nmod+j+n-the    time-n 10530
    other-j nmod+j+n-the    hand-n 5519
```

I have been trying this sort command, which should do the trick

```
sort input | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $1*$4}'
```

and it runs out of memory. Any suggestions on something that may be a bit more optimized to handle larger data files?? Thanks

Comment: How do you define duplicates? Same three columns? Add expected output so it is more clear.

Comment: See updated question -- I included desired results.

Comment: It is still not clear what you want. Why does the output contain two lines with `other-j nmod+j+n-the    hand-n`?

Comment: Sorry! Updated desired results - they are accurate now, I made an error in writing it. It is just summing the duplicates from Cols 1-3 and adding the freqs. in Col4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is running out of memory it is because of `sort` as `uniq` and `awk` only consume constant amounts of memory. You can run multiple sorts in parallel with GNU parallel, e.g. from the manual:

```
cat bigfile | parallel --pipe --files sort | parallel -Xj1 sort -m {} ';' rm {} >bigfile.sort
```

> Here bigfile is split into blocks of around 1MB, each block ending in
>   '\n' (which is the default for --recend). Each block is passed to sort
>   and the output from sort is saved into files. These files are passed
>   to the second parallel that runs sort -m on the files before it
>   removes the files. The output is saved to bigfile.sort.

When the file is sorted you can stream it through the `uniq`/`awk` pipe you were using, e.g.:

```
cat bigfile.sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $1*$4}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an array in `awk` you can do it all together, no need to `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2,$3]+=$4} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
first-jnmod+j+n-thetime-n 8749
ast-jnmod+j+nyear-n 1000
same-jnmod+j+n-thetime-n 10530
last-jnmod+j+nnight-n 13075
last-jnmod+j+nyear-n 9492
other-jnmod+j+n-thehand-n 5519
```

As this is using col 1, 2, 3 as indexes, then they are written all together. This can be solved having them in another array:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2,$3]+=$4; b[$1,$2,$3]=$1" "$2" "$3} END{for (i in a) print b[i], a[i]}' a
first-j nmod+j+n-the time-n 8749
ast-j nmod+j+n year-n 1000
same-j nmod+j+n-the time-n 10530
last-j nmod+j+n night-n 13075
last-j nmod+j+n year-n 9492
other-j nmod+j+n-the hand-n 5519
```

Comment: Thanks, on a sample file it seems to work quite well although I made a small alternation for my exact input `$ awk '{a[$1,$2,$3]+=$4; b[$1,$2,$3]=$1"\t"$2"\t"$3} END{for (i in a) print b[i], a[i]}'` . Do you think that this could work on a file up to 10GB in size? or better to keep working in pieces and concatenating?

Comment: The array will become quite big, but should work, @owwoow14. Note that piping in three blocks as you did may make it slower. Can you check it out with `time` in front of the command and then let me know?

Comment: update: trying on a file that is 7.6 GB, the process in progress for 80 min. -- still did not print to output // using 8G of vm in server. crossing fingers that it will output...

Comment: sorry, after +13 hours sucking the server dry for everything it was worth (+16g) - had to kill it. system admin was not so happy with me.

Comment: It is difficult to say with real data, but maybe you can test this: get 1 GB of file and check how long does it to take to 1) with my script. 2) sorting the file and then using a awk version that not stores all the values in an array. Depending on what's faster, then proceed. It is strange that it took that much :(

Answer (score 2):

`sort` and other purely magical UNIX tools are as optimized as they -- probably -- can be. If you're counting entries in a file, and their unique occurrences don't fit in memory, loading them up to memory won't be a good solution -- this is the fastest approach, otherwise.

Apart from this, sorting the file -- `O(n log n)` --, and later counting the entries -- `O(n)` -- will certainly be the best solution -- unless you keep a `k`-size map of entries in memory, and keep on swapping data from mem to disk whenever a `k + 1` key tries to be added to the map. Considering this, your solution (the one-liner with `sort + uniq + awk`) just needs a little tap.

Try to `sort` the file externally, using `sort`'s magical abilities to do so; after that, the count will require at most one entry to be kept in memory -- which pretty much addresses your problem. The final *two-liner* could be something like:

```
sort -T <directory_for_temp_files> <input> > <output>
awk '{
    if (cur == "$1 $3") { freq += $4; }
    else { printf "%s %d\n", cur, freq; cur = "$1 $3"; freq = $4; }
}' < <output> > <final_output>
```